# Less compilation all empty elements

Tags: compilation, less

How can i do to compilation all empty elements from .less to .css?
for example

```
.nav-tab{
  &__item{
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

It was compilated in: 
`.nav-tab__item{margin: 10px;}` 
But i need:

```
.nav-tab{} .nav-tab__item{margin: 10px;}
```

It work if i add any properties, but without it no compilation:

```
.nav-tab{}
```

I tried WinLess and Gulp-less
p.s. i need it for "Emmet LiveStyle". first: add selector, second: fill its with help DevTools of Chrome

Comment: Why do you need this `.nav-tab{}` anyway? It is going to do nothing, isn't it?

Comment: @Harry because .nav-tab{} is only conteiner for properties. I will fill its with help DevTools of Chrome

Comment: In Chrome Dev tools, you can add a selector itself and so you don't need the container to be present in the CSS at all. Just click on the New Style Rule icon (the + icon).

Comment: Alternatively, you can ditch LiveStyle and leverage ["watch mode" for LESS](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-watch-mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a fake ruleset (e.g., `ignore: me;`) or insert a comment:

```less
.nav-tab {
    /* force LESS to generate an empty ruleset */

    &__item { margin: 10px; }
}
```

Should result in the following CSS:

```css
.nav-tab { /* force LESS to generate an empty ruleset */ }
.nav-tab__item { margin: 10px; }
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.test%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%2F**%2F%5Cn%20%20%26__foo%20%7B%20margin%3A%2010px%3B%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)</kbd>

Comment: thank you. Your hack is maybe helpful for create snippets

Comment: up: fake ruleset only without bugs with LiveStyle